# If $G$ is nilpotent $N$ is normal in $G$ then $G/N$ is nilpotent .

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In proving the above lemma i have a small doubt :

define $\pi : G \to \frac{G}{N}$ , then if $G'$ denotes the derived subgroup of $G$ .

why does the following hold or not hold $\pi (G') =\frac{G'N}{N}$ ?

ie . i don't quite understand what $\pi (G' ) =\frac {G'N}{N} $ is ?

I hope my question is clear . 
Thanks for your help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your question

> why does the following hold or not hold $\pi (G') =\frac{G'N}{N}$?

This is a general fact. The subgroups of $G/N$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the subgroups of $H$ which contain $N$. The correspondence is best seem starting from a subgroup $\mathfrak{H}$ of $G/N$; then the corresponding subgroup in $G$ is $\pi^{-1}(\mathfrak{H}) = \{ x \in G : \pi(x) \in \mathfrak{H} \}$.

If $H \le G$, then its image under $\pi : G \to G/N$ is $HN/N$. In fact, $$\pi(H) = \{ \pi(x) : x \in H \} = \{ xN : x \in H \}.$$ Now you may be tempted to write this as $H/N$, but this notation is used when $N \le H$. To fix this, note that $$\{ xN : x \in H \} = \{ xnN : x \in H, n \in N \} = HN/N.$$
Written this way, you see how the subgroup $\pi(H)$ of $G/N$ corresponds to the subgroup $HN$ of $G$, with $N \le HN$.

Comment: can u tell me What is $H$ , is it a subgroup of $G$ that contain $N$ ?

Comment: @Theorem, any subgroup. Take $H=G'$ in your case.

Comment: Sir , i am still confused with the difference of $HN/N$ and simply $H/N$ .

Comment: $\,H/N\,$ is defined iff $\,N\le H\,$ , otherwise one *has to take* $\,HN\,$ instead...try to google "correspondence theorem for groups"

Answer (score 1):

$$\pi(G'):=\langle\,[xN,yN]\;;\;xN,yN\in G/N\,\rangle=\langle\,[x,y]N\;;\;x,y\in G\,\rangle=G'N/N$$